# how to use windbg track memory allocated with VirtualAlloc?

Tags: winapi, windbg, heap-memory

you know how you can use gflags wih +ust to get the call stack paired with each allocation.  you can then use !heap in windbg to diagnose leaks?

I want to do this with large allocations made through VirtualAlloc.  As far as I can tell VirtualAlloc bypasses the gflags/!heap extensions?

I'm hoping someone can confirm

a) !heap walks the list of allocated memory in each heap - but not the allocated memory that came from VirtualAlloc

b)  when you allocate a huge chunk of memory via new/malloc that goes to LocalAlloc() and then to VirtualAlloc() where it bypasses the call stack logging

I'm really hoping someone can assist me in debugging this sort of leak.  if the allocations were smaller I'd have no trouble with !heap

Answer (score 2):

You can try LeakDiag which works on a number of different types of memory including memory originiating from VirtualAlloc.

Answer (score 1):

The heap functions operate at a higher level than the `Virtual*` functions; in fact, the heap must call VirtualAlloc to add more memory to the process address space. `!heap` isn't going to help you with `Virtual*` calls.

Comment: understood,  however it looks like large calls to HeapAlloc() short circuit directly to VirtualAlloc() where they are not tracked.  I'm not making direct calls to VirtualAlloc

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

The operating system provides memory via VirtualAlloc() only. That works fine, but the granularity is not good: it can only provide 64kB at a time. That's why Microsoft has implemented different heap managers, e.g. the C++ heap manager or the .NET heap manager. Those get memory from the OS in 64kB blocks and provide it to a C++ or .NET program in smaller chunks.

`!heap` and related commands only work for the C++ heap manager. To inspect the .NET heap, you need the [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) extension for WinDbg.

#### Regarding your questions

> As far as I can tell VirtualAlloc bypasses the gflags/!heap extensions?

The GFlags `+ust` flag is specific to C++ heap allocations. The `!heap` commands are also specific to the C++ heap manager, so yes, none of these will care about VirtualAlloc() calls.

However, I would not say, VirtualAlloc() "bypasses" them, which would be a statement that it goes through the C++ heap manager. It's rather the opposite: it's on a lower level than the heap manager operates.

> a) !heap walks the list of allocated memory in each heap - but not the allocated memory that came from VirtualAlloc

Yes, for the same reason.

> b) when you allocate a huge chunk of memory via new/malloc that goes to LocalAlloc() and then to VirtualAlloc() where it bypasses the call stack logging

Basically yes. There is a point where it's no longer worth to split the memory into smaller regions. Obviously allocating 64kB for a 2 byte variable is too much waste.

Microsoft drew the line at ~ 512 kB as documented in [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx) (look for the term 0x7FFF8). So when you allocate more than 512 kB, it will not use the heap manager any more but the raw memory block of VirtualAlloc(). In the worst case, there's an overhead of 12% (64kB waste when you allocate 512kB + 1 Byte).

#### Don't worry

There are other tools to recognize larger memory leaks that arise from VirtualAlloc(). The WinDbg command `!address` is helpful and [Rohitab API monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) can help. As suggested by others, you can also try LeakDiag or commercial memory leak analyzers.